# Do MySql connections closed from Jdbc stay opened for some time?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I get the following error accessing to a MySql Database from Jdbc:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
```

At the same time I am monitoring my connections. I added a counter that counts any opening and closing. The error ouccurs when I get to 380 opened and closed connections within 3 minutes.
Is it possible that it takes some time for MySql to acutally close the connection so that there are still too many opened even though I have send a command to close them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just assuming certain points that might be the reason.

1. MySql Connections are maintained by MySql Connection Manager so once connection is released Manager will decide to kill that thread or return it back to pool.
2. In some cases if MySql Resultset is not closed after retrieving data and connection has been close on that time sending it back to pool might have some latency issue.

These two are points that i think might cause that, but i am not sure if these are correct or not. 
There could be other reasons that i am not knowing about.
Hope it gives you some idea.